# hide/show date base on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a php page with a search function that has a dropdown menu that includes student, id, registered_date. Now I have a search bar and a date(start date - end date). I want to show the date picker when a user selects registered_date on the dropdown table, but I don't know how. I know for a fact that they use `.show()` and `.hide()` but I don't know how to use it on a selection.

Here is my code so far.

```
Category<select name="category" id="category">
        <option value='1' id="1">Student</option>
        <option value='2' id="2">ID</option>
        <option value='3' id="3">Registration_date</option>
        <option value='4' id="4">Course</option>
        </select>

Search Text<input type="text" name="txtsearch" placeholder="Type to Search" />
    Date Start: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date1">
    Date End: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="date2">
```

Here is my javascript/jquery

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});

  });
   $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});
  });



****I dont know what the code for the hide and show part

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
   $( "#datepicker" ).hide();
  $( "#datepicker2" ).hide();

      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});
      $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});
            $("#category").on('change',function(){
           if($("#category").val() == 3){
             $( "#datepicker" ).show();
             $( "#datepicker2" ).show();
             }else{
            $( "#datepicker" ).hide();
            $( "#datepicker2" ).hide();
  }

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Category<select name="category" id="category">
        <option value='1' id="1">Student</option>
        <option value='2' id="2">ID</option>
        <option value='3' id="3">Registration_date</option>
        <option value='4' id="4">Course</option>
        </select>

Search Text<input type="text" name="txtsearch" placeholder="Type to Search" />
    Date Start: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date1">
    Date End: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="date2">
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your question, you can use something like this:

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).show();
 $( "#datepicker" ).hide();
```

Any selector followed by `.show()` or `.hide()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#category').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).val() == '3'){
    $("#datepicker").hide();
  } 
  else{
    $("#datepicker").show();
  }
```

});

This will show/hide your `datepicker` if you select registered_date.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this:

```
$('#category').on('change', function(){
    if( $(this).val() == "3" ){
        $("#datepicker").show();
        $("#datepicker2").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind on change event on select and check whether selected option is registration date or not.. than hide/show date picker accordingly...

```
$('#category').change(function(event) {
        /* Act on the event */
        if($(this).val() == 3){
            $( "#datepicker" ).show();
        }else{
            $( "#datepicker" ).hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#datepicker, #datepicker2').datepicker();
$('#daterange').hide();

$('#category').on('change', function(){
    if( $(this).val() == "3" ){
        $('#daterange').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#daterange').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Category<select name="category" id="category">
        <option value='1' id="1">Student</option>
        <option value='2' id="2">ID</option>
        <option value='3' id="3">Registration_date</option>
        <option value='4' id="4">Course</option>
        </select>

Search Text<input type="text" name="txtsearch" placeholder="Type to Search" />
<div id = "daterange">
    Date Start: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date1">
    Date End: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="date2">
    </div>
```

Here is what you want. Place your both datepicker in one div and make them hide, show together.

**[FIDDLE (Example)](https://jsfiddle.net/tasqyjjs/)**

**HTML**

```
Category<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value='1' id="1">Student</option>
    <option value='2' id="2">ID</option>
    <option value='3' id="3">Registration_date</option>
    <option value='4' id="4">Course</option>
    </select>

Search Text<input type="text" name="txtsearch" placeholder="Type to Search"  />
<div id = "daterange">
Date Start: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date1">
Date End: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="date2">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#datepicker, #datepicker2').datepicker();
$('#daterange').hide();

$('#category').on('change', function(){
if( $(this).val() == "3" ){
    $('#daterange').show();
}
else
{
    $('#daterange').hide();
}
});
```